# indicator function on partition

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Consider the interval $[0,b]$ and divide it into n equal parts, i.e $(b_{k-1},b_k]$ for $k=1,\dots,n$ and $b_k:= k \frac{b}{n} $ Consider the function $f$ defined on $[0,b]$ and the following:

$$f_n(s)=\sum_{k=1}^n f(b_{k-1}) 1_{(b_{k-1},b_k]}(s)$$
for $s \in [0,b] $

I wonder why  for $n \rightarrow \infty$ $f_n(s)$ converges to $f(s)$ since the indicator $1_{(b_{k 1},b_{k-1} ]}$ would always equal $0$?

Comment: Is $g(s)$ a function of $k$ and $n$ as well as $s$?

Comment: @Yes I only wanted to abbreviate slightly.

Comment: k is the number of intervals, depending on the length of each of those, which is given by $b/n$

Comment: What makes you think that $f(s) 1_{(b_{k-1},b_k]}(s) \to f(s)$ for any $s\in[0,b]$?

Comment: Maybe I should rewrite it and consider $b_{k-1} + \Delta  $ for $\Delta \rightarrow 0$

Comment: @SangchulLee. $k$ doesn't depend on $n$, but the range of $k$ does: $k=1,\ldots,n$ For $n=1$ there is only one part: $(0, b]$, for $n=2$ there are two parts: $(0,b/2]$ and $(b/2,b]$, and so on.

Comment: @md2perpe: I makes no sense for me, but it read it in some script.

Comment: @md2perpe, Does that mean that we are considering a double sequence of functions $$f_{n,k}(s)=f(s)\mathbf{1}_{(b_{k-1},b_k]}(s), \qquad n\geq 1 \text{ and } 1\leq k\leq n \quad ? $$ My question persists: What does it mean to take limit $n\to\infty$ to this double sequence? Do we examine an arbitrary choice of subsequence along $k=k(n)\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$? To be honest, I guess what OP actually want to consider is the sum, such as $$f_n(s)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(b_{k-1})\mathbf{1}_{(b_{k-1},b_k]}(s),$$ that can be regarded as a discretization of $f$.

Comment: @SangchulLee: Sorry yes I mean that.

Comment: I thought I had written the sum. Sorry for that.

Comment: With the sum it makes sense, and to me it is trivial. Why do you, @Alif, think that the indicator function is always $0$?

Comment: @md2perpe: Since then the indicator becomes $1_{(b_{k-1}, b_{k-1}]} =1_{\emptyset}=0$

Comment: @Alif, In its current form, we have $f_n(s)=f(s)$ for all $s\in(0,b]$ and $f_n(0)=0$, so the answer is quite trivial. I guess you need other than $f(s)$ in the summand. Anyway, even though each subinterval shrinks as $n$ grows, that is compensated by the increasing number of subintervals. Overall, each point $s$ in $(0, b]$ is covered by exactly one subinterval for each $n$. So, even if we lose the quality of "piecewise expression" in the limit, that does not mean that $f_n$ becomes trivial in the limit.

Comment: Thank you for the intution. But what about the indicator. It is always 0 in the limit. If I change $f(s) $ to $f(b_{k-1})$. Why do I get the same convergence?

Comment: From where do you get $1_{(b_{k-1}, b_{k-1}]}$?

Comment: I could write $(b_{k-1}, b_{k-1} + b/n]$ for $ n$ to infinity.